# How can get byte of pdf before download? - Grails

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdf, byte

I can download pdf file from **AWS**, download is working fine but I need get byte before download.

```
        String awsBucket = params.awsBucket
        String awsKey = params.awsKey
        String fileName = params.fileName
        String pdfLink = params.pdfLink

         File file = grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource('WSCredential.properties').file
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)
                AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new PropertiesCredentials(fileInputStream))

                GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(awsBucket, awsKey)
                userReceipt = s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest)
          if (userReceipt)
                {
                    response.setContentType("application/image/png") 
                    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"${fileName}\"")
                    response.outputStream << userReceipt.getObjectContent()

                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the size of PDF, then you can use [HeadObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_HeadObject.html).